# Plots in JMH [Java Micro-Benchmarking Harness]

Tags: benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I have been reading about [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). But I couldn't find a way to generate plots using this. Does JMH support plotting? Or are there third party libraries for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JMH does not support plotting**. You can **write** out the performance **results into a file** (e.g. with `-rf csv` or `-rf json`), and use whatever plotting tool you are familiar with. Or, you can extract the performance data from `RunResult` instance you got from Java API, and parse/render it with any embedded library.

**If you use settings to observe single call executions time** (or batch calls) and you want to see plot of each durations (something like last plot [here](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/)), you can combine settings:

```
@Measurement(batchSize = 1000, iterations = 500)
@BenchmarkMode({Mode.SingleShotTime})
```

And a bit of scripting to get desired data in csv. In settings like this, there is only summary data in resulting csv from jmh.

```
mvn package && java -jar target/benchmarks.jar -foe true -rf csv | tee output.txt
N=5 # set here number of benchmarks plus 2
grep Iteration -A 3 output.txt | grep -v Warmup | sed 's/$/,/' | xargs -l$N | sed 's/,$//'
```

It will output something like:

```
Iteration 1: 93.915 ±(99.9%) 2066.879 s/op, readerA: 28.487 s/op, readerB: 28.525 s/op, writer: 224.735 s/op, --
Iteration 2: 100.483 ±(99.9%) 1265.993 s/op, readerA: 59.927 s/op, readerB: 60.912 s/op, writer: 180.610 s/op, --
Iteration 3: 76.458 ±(99.9%) 760.395 s/op, readerA: 52.513 s/op, readerB: 52.276 s/op, writer: 124.586 s/op, --
Iteration 4: 84.046 ±(99.9%) 1189.029 s/op, readerA: 46.112 s/op, readerB: 46.724 s/op, writer: 159.303 s/op, --
```

Comment: Could you please name some plotting tools which supports for this jmh.out file and a link for this RunResult Data Exctraction. I searched but no luck up to now.

Comment: Well, just about any sane tool reads CSV files: Libre/OpenOffice, R, etc.